# Google calendar in the terminal

Tags: ubuntu, gnome-terminal, calendar

I'm looking to use the terminal more and more, and I'd like to find a terminal calendar app that can sync with Google calendar.

I'm running ubuntu 14.04

Comment: have you tried [elinks](http://elinks.or.cz/) ?

Comment: I have not, but I'm looking for more of an "app" and not a browser replacement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at:

[gcalcli](https://github.com/insanum/gcalcli),

and also:

[remind](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/remind) , which has PHP scripts to convert iCAL entries to Remind format.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like what I want. I'll give it a try when I get home.

Comment: You might also have luck with vdirsyncer + khal

Answer (score 4):

[Emacs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs) has an extension called [Org mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Org-mode) (Ubuntu: [org-mode](http://packages.ubuntu.com/org-mode)) which does, errrm, [stuff](http://orgmode.org/features.html), including [agenda](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-custom-agenda-commands.html) [facilities](http://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-Views.html#Agenda-Views). The Org mode agenda can be synchronized with Google Calendar, though it appears not to be foolproof; see [the Org mode Google Calendar Synchronization tutorial](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-google-sync.html), and try [org-caldav](https://github.com/dengste/org-caldav) or [org-gcal](https://github.com/myuhe/org-gcal.el) (both installable with `M-x package-install` in Emacs).

Emacs opens a GUI window by default; you can force it to open in a terminal by running `emacs -nw`. You can open GUI windows and terminal windows in the same Emacs instance; run `emacsclient -nw` from a terminal to open an Emacs window in the terminal, or `emacsclient -c` to open a GUI window.

Comment: This seems like a great solution, however I learned Vim and can't for the life of me get used to using both.

Comment: @JonathonBly So use [Viper](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ViperMode) or [Vimpulse](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Vimpulse) or [Evil](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/Evil)

Comment: I've tried evil, but it felt way to strange for me. I might give your first two options a try, though. Thanks.